# How to find repeating pattern in R string?

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have the following string:

```
v = c("fam gen geo gen")
```

I need a regular expression, which will find a repeating pattern in this string. For example, if I go with:

```
str_extract(v, "*regular expression*")
```

The output should be:

```
"gen"
```

Can you please come up with a regular expression for this case?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Will there only ever be more than one substring that repeats? What output would you like in that case? Will the substring always be 3 characters? Will space ` ` always be the delimiter? Please provide more detail about the possible input and the desired ouput.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a regex with "backreference":

```
sub(".*?(\\w+).+\\1", "\\1", v)
```

If there is a group of letters `(\\w+)` followed by some (at least 1) other elements `.+` then the first captured group of letters appears again `\\1` (backreference), then return this group of letters (second argument to the sub function).

Answer (score 0):

ok I'm going to assume that you are trying to create a vector with 4 elements of `char`

Instead of

```
v = c("fam gen geo gen")
```

It should be

```
v = c("fam", "gen", "geo", "gen")
```

Then

```
v[duplicated(v)]
```

In the case that you have over two repetitions of an element and you only want the duplicated element to be returned once, you can use `anyDuplicated`

```
v <- c("fam", "gen", "geo", "gen", "gen")
v[duplicated(v)] 
>"gen" "gen"

v[anyDuplicated(v)]
>"gen"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a different assumption than Nomad. I'm going to assume that you have a pure string, and then I'm going to split it by the assumed delimiter  
 (space).

```
v = c("fam gen geo gen")

vec <- unlist(
    strsplit(v, " ")
)

vec[anyDuplicated(vec)]
[1] "gen"
```